# How do I run pytest on all-modules?

Tags: python, nose, pytest

nose has an all-modules=1 configuration value which makes its test collector look in all files, not just the ones following its naming conventions: .http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/allmodules.html

What is the equivalent way to do this with pytest? i.e. I do not want to rename all our test modules when switching to pytest.

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://pytest.org/latest/example/pythoncollection.html#changing-naming-conventions

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per: http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#confval-python_files

I've added these lines to my `setup.cfg` file:

```
[pytest]
python_files=*py
```